# Adding an additional argument to an argparse argument

Tags: python, argparse

I'm new to using the arparse module in python and am hoping someone can help me with the following problem.
I am specifying a variable number of files as inputs using:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Get Files')    
parser.add_argument('-i','--input', help='Input file(s)',required=True, nargs='+') 
args = parser.parse_args()
```

I would like to specify a variable number of file inputs, each with an associated value of 1 or 2 and am not sure how to do this.

I would like the program to work so that my command line entry should be:

```
MyProgram.py -i myfile.txt 2 secondfile.txt 1 ...
```

Once I have this working how do I call each file in the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is functional. You could use the [grouper recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) to loop through `args.input` two items at a time:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Get Files')    
parser.add_argument('-i','--input', help='Input file(s)',required=True, nargs='+') 
args = parser.parse_args()
for filename, num in zip(*[iter(args.input)]*2):
    print(filename, num)
    # with open(filename) as f:
    #     ....
```

yields

```
('myfile.txt', '2')
('secondfile.txt', '1')
```

Comment: It is worth noting that since python 3.12, `grouper` recipe is a builtin function in itertools named `batched`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.batched
The only difference is that batched does not fill the last group in case the length of the iterable is not fully dividable by `n`

Answer (score 1):

It would be clearer to have `-i` once for each pair of inputs, like this:

```
parser.add_argument("-i", "--input", nargs=2, action='append')
```

Now, `args.input` would be a list of lists, like so

```
 [ ['myfile.txt', 2], ['secondfile.txt', 1] ]
```

It does require slightly more typing for the user, since `-i` needs to be explicitly typed once per file.

Another option is to specify each argument as a single word, then parse the word using the `type` argument. I would get rid of the `-i` argument as well and use positional arguments for required "options".

```
parser.add_argument('input', nargs='+', type=lambda x: x.rsplit(":", 2))
```

Usage would be

```
myscript.py myfile.txt:1 secondfile.txt:2 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be best off using `sys.argv` as,

```
import sys, os

variables = list()
filenames = list()

if( len( sys.argv ) > 1 ):
    if( sys.argv[1] == '-i' )or( sys.argv[1] == '--input' ):
        N = len( sys.argv[1:] )
        for i in range( 2, N, 2 ):
            variables.append( int( sys.argv[i] ) )
            filenames.append( sys.argv[i+1] )

for file in filenames:
    # do something here
    os.system( 'less '+file )
```

I haven't tested this, but that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Get Files')    
parser.add_argument('-i','--input', help='Input file(s)',
    required=True, nargs='+', action='append')

args = parser.parse_args()
```